# Google maps/streetview widget

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I wish to insert, on my personal site, a Google Maps/Street View widget like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I have only found this [simple Street View example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) which lacks the "from" and "to" fields. Plus, the particularity of the first widget (in the screenshot) is that Street View doesn't need Flash Player.

Can someone can point me to a widget like this (with Street View ability), which also provides "from" and "to" fields, to calculate and browse itineraries?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, go to maps.google.com, type in the address that you want to show up in the street view, then zoom into the street view.

Once you have done that, look just to the left of the street view.  You will see a chain icon that says 'link' when you hover over it.  It will give you two things for you to choose from:

1) a direct link to the streetview, and

2) an snippet of code to embed directly into the html of a website.

If you're putting this on a webpage, copy the iframe snippet and paste it into the HTML file of the page on which you want it to appear.  You can even customize how it will appear by clicking the "customize and preview embedded map" link.

Unfortunately, you cannot link straight to the directions field.  Google uses javascript to display these fields.  However, it's not a huge problem, since all your visitors will have to do is click "directions" and those fields will appear.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In anyway is possible to know where this widget (http://s22.postimg.org/kry4mboe9/GMaps_Widget.png) come from? Is exactly what i need.